# Why does the content of one scenario in a case decide whether the other's content should be right trimmed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My co-workers and I have encountered a strange behaviour in SQL-Server.

Consider the following code:

```
select a = 
    case when 1=1 then
        'a '
    else
        'b '
    end + 'c'
```

One would should reasonable assume that the above code produces the string 'a c'.  And it does.

However, if I extend the `else`'s constant ('b ') with an additional space, something strange happens:

```
select a = 
    case when 1=1 then
        'a '
    else
        'b  '
    end + 'c'
```

Now the result is 'ac', the space from 'a ' has disappeared.  The reverse is also true:

```
select a = 
    case when 1=0 then
        'a  '
    else
        'b '
    end + 'c'
```

This will yield 'bc'.  So whenever constant not being returned is longer than the constant being returned, the constant being returned is right trimmed.

And it's only a right trim, because the following code will yield ' ac':

```
select a = 
    case when 1=1 then
        ' a '
    else
        'b   '
    end + 'c'
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour?  I assumed it might have something to do with cleaning up strings for trailing whitespace, but then why does it only happen when the constant not being returned is longer?

The above behaviour have been observed on a SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, this behaviour do not appear to be reproducible on a standard installations of SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: What version and release of SQL-Server and can you reproduce it on SQLFiddle?

Comment: Curious, maybe it has something to do with my query execution settings.  Currently, I only have the "SET ARITHABORT" flag set and no ANSI flags.  And I am using SQL Server 2014.  And I cannot reproduce the behaviour on SQLFiddle.  It must be something to do with our settings.  I wonder what settings are causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your session has `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`, which will trim trailing spaces from `varchar`.  Try running with `SET ANSI_PADDING ON` (recommended setting).

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;

--trims trailing spaces
SELECT a = 
    CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN
        'a '
    ELSE
        'b  '
    END + 'c';

--does not trim trailing spaces
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

SELECT a = 
    CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN
        'a '
    ELSE
        'b  '
    END + 'c';
```

**EDIT:**

Per the [SQL Server ANSI_PADDING documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx), the setting should only apply to column storage, not to expression results.  I asked about this behavior and SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog did some regression tests using ancient SQL Server versions and identified this behavior as a bug introduced in SQL 7.  It was corrected in SQL 2000, but only for `ANSI_PADDING ON`; `ANSI_PADDING OFF` continues to misbehave to this day.

I strongly suggest you change your code as to not rely on undocumented and buggy behavior.  This bug may be fixed in a future SQL Server version or patch and break your code.  Explicitly use the `RTRIM` function if your application needs trailing spaces removed.

Comment: Yes.  This appears to be the correct answer.  Thank you.  We might want to consider re-enabling this flag.

Comment: While your answer is useful, it still doesn't explain why it behaves that way without `ANSI_PADDING` on.  It seems to be a particularly strange behaviour regardless of how you look at it.  Sybase doesn't behave this way, so it cannot be a backwards compatibility issue with that.

Comment: @Svip, it's been nearly 20 years since I worked with Sybase.  Are you saying Sybase behaves differently with `ANSI_PADDING OFF`?  Note that the client API may set session settings when connecting.  Modern APIs turn on this option by default.

Comment: `ANSI_PADDING` is not an option in Sybase.  In this scenario, Sybase behaves as if `ANSI_PADDING` was `ON`.

Comment: It seems then that newer versions of Sybase removed the `ANSI_PADDING` option entirely.  It is retained in MSSQL to only to avoid breaking legacy apps. Although both DBMS products share the same roots, they are quite different nowadays.

Comment: The reason we have `ANSI_PADDING` `OFF` is because our code expects trailing blanks to be trimmed.  So them being trimmed makes sense, but why does it only trim them when the other variable is longer?  The odd behaviour still is odd.  Having `ANSI_PADDING OFF` isn't supposed to mean 'behave strangely'.

Comment: I agree there is something odd with `ANSI_PADDING OFF` and the result of the `CASE` expression.  I'll try to find out more but the `OFF` setting is the road less traveled.

Comment: @Svip, I updated my answer to reflect this is a bug.